# SQL Server, show aggregate amount from multiple tables in single query

Tags: sql-server

I have these tables, each can have multiple rows.

- table ta (eid, amount)
- table tb (eid, amount)
- table tc (eid, amount)

Each table has data rows like this:

**ta:**

```
1001  100.00
1001   20.10
```

**tb:**

```
1001   200.00
1001   32.10
```

**tc:**

```
1001   300.00
1001   20.10
```

Solution I need: single row with eid and aggregate of each table's amount column

```
1001   120.10     232.10   320.10
```

I tried this but it is showing the  amount multiplied by number of tables I am using

```
select 
    ta.eid, 
    sum(ta.Amount) as taAmount, 
    sum(tb.Amount) as tbAmount, 
    sum(tc.Amount) as tcAmount
from 
    ta , tb, tc
where 
    ta.eid = tb.eid 
    and tb.eid = tc.eid
group by 
    ta.eid
```

Please help me know how it can be achieved ?

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 2, accepted):

make use of derived table or CTE to get the aggregate amount first

```
select ta.eid, ta.amount, tb.amount, tc.amount
from   (select eid, amount= sum(amount) from ta group by eid) ta
join   (select eid, amount= sum(amount) from tb group by eid) tb on ta.eid = tb.eid
join   (select eid, amount= sum(amount) from tc group by eid) tc on ta.eid = tc.eid
```

If the `eid` might not appear in all tables, you can get a list of eid and then `LEFT JOIN` to ta, tb, tc

```
select i.eid, ta.amount, tb.amount, tc.amount
from   (select eid from ta union select eid from tb union select eid from tc) i
left join (select eid, amount= sum(amount) from ta group by eid) ta on i.eid = ta.eid
left join (select eid, amount= sum(amount) from tb group by eid) tb on i.eid = tb.eid
left join (select eid, amount= sum(amount) from tc group by eid) tc on i.eid = tc.eid
```

Comment: I added left join to satisfy my need. But this query has one problem though, ta should have some values in it then only other table's value will show up .. otherwise I get Nulls.

Comment: see second query